# How to use $_SESSION in a included file

Tags: php, session

On every page that I access through index2.php, where my game is but the header file is included there. Do I need to use `$username = $_SESSION['username']` in every page if I have it in the header file? How do I do it?

Comment: Please don't put your entire question in the question title.  Summarize, then ask in the question body.  Thanks.

Comment: Ok thanks first post here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is if you include a page at the top of your script and it is defining the `$username` variable as the `$_SESSION` var, then **no** you do not need to set it on every page. However, that being said make sure you are checking to see if the session is set before setting it.

Example is if the user is guest you can do the following:

```
$username = "guest";
if(isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    $username = $_SESSION['username'];
}
```

Since your question was updated to ask how you do it you include the file using the following

```
include_once("path/to/file.php");
```

Comment: Thanks that answers my question I appreciate it it will save a little time and I have learned something I didn't know.

Comment: @TerryJ. You can also define your `session_start()` variable in that one file and include it to start the session for every page it is included on to ensure you get the values in the right order.

Answer (score 0):

```
session_start();

  $username = 'guest';

if(isset($_SESSION['username']))
{
    $username = $_SESSION['username'];    
}


require_once("path_to_session.php")
```

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310219/are-answers-that-contain-only-commented-code-acceptable